# invalid PHP version magento

Tags: php, magento, migration, version

I got the message Whoops, it looks like you have an invalid PHP version while I was migrating my website to localhost, I did all the steps I found on how to migrate the website to my localhost.

Even though Im using php version 5.4 it says that my php version is invalid that it should be 5.2 o higher

Im going crazy with this problem someone help me.

Comment: What setup are you using? Are you using WAMP, PHP inbuilt server, Apache, or IDE server? 
You can also check what version is RUNNING using echo phpversion();
It may be that you have multiple different versions of PHP installed.

Answer (score 0):

Download and upload this file on your root directory and check for results,

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento
```